# Logical AND operation with integers in C#

Tags: c#

When I do the following logical AND operation with numbers in C# I'm getting the following results:

```
 -3 & 3 = 1
 -1 & 1 = 1
  0 & 0 =0
```

but when I do **8 & -8 =8**
Can someone please explain how we are getting the result as 8?

Comment: Because with only one `&`, it's a bitwise operation, not a logical operation.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the numbers in hexadecimal format, it will help you understand how the calculation is performed.

Assuming you store the numbers as integers:

```
3  = 0x00000003
8  = 0x00000008 
-3 = 0xFFFFFFFD
-8 = 0xFFFFFFF8
```

Then if we zoom in on the smallest nibble (4-bits, consider the following):

For 3 & -3

```
  0 0 1 1
& 1 1 0 1
  -------
  0 0 0 1    =  1
```

For 8 & -8

```
  1 0 0 0
& 1 0 0 0
  -------
  1 0 0 0   = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

To see what is going on, you could use the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    show(8);
    show(-8);
}

static void show(int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{i,3} = 0b{Convert.ToString(i, 2).PadLeft(32, '0')}");
}
```

Output:

```
  8 = 0b00000000000000000000000000001000
 -8 = 0b11111111111111111111111111111000
```